# Post a message AFTER the user click the mouse button

Tags: c#, c++, api, winapi

I use SetWindowsHookEx to monitor another application. When the user click the mouse in the program I use PostMessage to send a message to the program.

The problem I have is that sometimes my message arrive **before** WM_LBUTTONUP. How do I ensure that my message will arrive **after** WM_LBUTTONUP?

I use [Gma.UserActivityMonitor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx) for monitoring and following code to send messages:

```
HookManager.MouseUp += HookManagerMouseUp;

void HookManagerMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   uint ret;
   uint attachedThredId = GetCurrentThreadId();
   uint attachedProcessId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(ActiveWindow, out ret);
   AttachThreadInputSafe(attachedThredId, attachedProcessId, true);


   PostMessage(ActiveControlInWindow, Message.KeyDown, 'A', 0x1);
   PostMessage(ActiveControlInWindow, Message.KeyUp,   'A', 0xC0010001);

   AttachThreadInputSafe(attachedThredId, attachedProcessId, false);
}
```

I am using PostMessage to send keystrokes is because I want to do it even if host application is not active.

The hook in Gma.UserActivityMonitor is as follows:

```
s_MouseDelegate = MouseHookProc;
s_MouseHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(
  WH_MOUSE_LL,
  s_MouseDelegate,
  Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]),
    0);
```

I use Spy++ to monitor the messages that arrives to the application. When the messages arrives in the right order I get following result:

```
S   WM_MOUSEACTIVATE hwndTopLevel:00030A46 nHittest:HTCLIENT uMsg:WM_LBUTTONDOWN
R   WM_MOUSEACTIVATE fuActivate:MA_ACTIVATE
S   WM_KILLFOCUS hwndGetFocus:00020A32
R   WM_KILLFOCUS
S   WM_IME_SETCONTEXT fSet:1 iShow:C000000F
R   WM_IME_SETCONTEXT
S   WM_SETFOCUS hwndLoseFocus:00030A46
R   WM_SETFOCUS
P   WM_LBUTTONDOWN fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:278 yPos:73
S   WM_ERASEBKGND hdc:0E010DEE
R   WM_ERASEBKGND fErased:True
P   WM_LBUTTONUP fwKeys:0000 xPos:278 yPos:73
S   WM_CAPTURECHANGED hwndNewCapture:00000000
R   WM_CAPTURECHANGED
P   WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_OEM_5 cRepeat:1 ScanCode:00 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
P   WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_OEM_5 cRepeat:1 ScanCode:01 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
P   WM_CHAR chCharCode:'167' (167) cRepeat:1 ScanCode:00 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
P   WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:'2' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:00 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
P   WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:'2' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:01 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
P   WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:'2' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:00 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
P   WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:'2' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:01 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
P   WM_CHAR chCharCode:'50' (50) cRepeat:1 ScanCode:00 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
P   WM_CHAR chCharCode:'50' (50) cRepeat:1 ScanCode:00 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
S   WM_KILLFOCUS hwndGetFocus:(null)
R   WM_KILLFOCUS
S   WM_IME_SETCONTEXT fSet:0 iShow:C000000F
R   WM_IME_SETCONTEXT
```

When the messages arrives in the wrong order I get following result (Note that WM_LBUTTONUP arrive **after** WM_CHAR have been handled):

```
S   WM_MOUSEACTIVATE hwndTopLevel:00030A46 nHittest:HTCLIENT uMsg:WM_LBUTTONDOWN
R   WM_MOUSEACTIVATE fuActivate:MA_ACTIVATE
S   WM_KILLFOCUS hwndGetFocus:00020A32
R   WM_KILLFOCUS
S   WM_IME_SETCONTEXT fSet:1 iShow:C000000F
R   WM_IME_SETCONTEXT
S   WM_SETFOCUS hwndLoseFocus:00030A46
R   WM_SETFOCUS
P   WM_LBUTTONDOWN fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:329 yPos:166
S   WM_ERASEBKGND hdc:1E0117FD
R   WM_ERASEBKGND fErased:True
P   WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:VK_OEM_5 cRepeat:1 ScanCode:00 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
P   WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:VK_OEM_5 cRepeat:1 ScanCode:01 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
P   WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:'2' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:00 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
P   WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:'2' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:01 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
P   WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:'2' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:00 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
P   WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:'2' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:01 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
P   WM_CHAR chCharCode:'167' (167) cRepeat:1 ScanCode:00 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
P   WM_CHAR chCharCode:'50' (50) cRepeat:1 ScanCode:00 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
P   WM_CHAR chCharCode:'50' (50) cRepeat:1 ScanCode:00 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
P   WM_LBUTTONUP fwKeys:0000 xPos:329 yPos:166
S   WM_CAPTURECHANGED hwndNewCapture:00000000
R   WM_CAPTURECHANGED
S   WM_KILLFOCUS hwndGetFocus:(null)
R   WM_KILLFOCUS
S   WM_IME_SETCONTEXT fSet:0 iShow:C000000F
R   WM_IME_SETCONTEXT
```

What I can see it is random when one or the other occurs. If I add a delay before I post the messages, it works. But I don't want to use a delay.

Comment: why don't you post the relevant code here so that we can see how you do it?

Comment: @Nawaz I have added simplified code of what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of reasons that your seeing this behavior (other hooks, system modal loops), but the most obvious one is that your hook gets notified before the WM_nBUTTONUP message is posted to the thread.

The only sure-fire way you can get the desired behavior is with a global hook so that you are executing in the process that will get the message. It is likely you will need to use a WH_CALLWNDPROCRET hook so that your hook gets called *after* the message is processed.

Answer (score -1):

Use a MOUSE_LL hook, and post the message when you receive the `WM_*BUTTONUP`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644986(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Just what I've done, but it only works sometimes, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have any better criteria than "some of the time"? (e.g. the window needs to be active, ...) Do the PostMessage's get executed? Does any of the methods fail? With what werror code? Is ActiveControlInWindow the correct window handle?

Comment: What I can see it is random when one or the other occurs. I have edit the question to show the result in spy+++. And the KEYUP and KEYDOWN are arrives to the application as you can se. So it can't be any error in that.